# how could let sonarqube pickup jacoco test coverage report

Tags: grails, sonarqube, jacoco, grails-4, jacoco-plugin

I have gradle project which use jacoco plugin

```
plugins{

    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.0'

}

test{

    exclude 'xx'

}

jacocoTestReport{

    dependsOn test
    reports{
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
    }
}

plugins.withType(JacocoPlugin){

    tasks["test"].finalizedBy 'jacocoTestReport'

}
```

now my local I can see the report of test coverage at default location reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html
Our comapany using a jules build and then do sonarQube analysis, and seems did not pickup my jacoco report

Any other information I should put in?

Comment: how do you do your sonar analysis? is it a gradle task, or an external scanner?

Comment: it is external scanner, and jenkins build then scan,